# Colour High Contrast effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, effects, contrast

I've spent ages so far fiddling with adjustments and filters in the hope that I can recreate the effect shown in this picture.

I've tried posterising other similar effects, but I want to keep the level of detail in the face as it is kept in this photo.

Thanks in advance :)

[image: Effect I am going for]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a gradient map over the image:

Layer > new adjustment layer > gradient map

Then select 2 colours you would like to use in the gradient from the properties panel.

Answer (score 2):

Hum... I basicly see:

1) **Grayscale image**. You can **crop** the black and white values **using levels**. Normally you just adjust it enough so the graph touches the borders, but in this case you need to move that graph further away.

2) Change the blend mode to **multiply** and use whichever color you need in a layer or background below it.

The specifics would depend on the aplication you are using but the idea is the same.